# The ability of the @CurrentIteration macro to accept a team is disabled (On Premise TFS)

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

TFS URL : http://tfs.{my-organization-name}.com:8080/tfs/

TFS : On Premise

Version : TFS 2018 Update 2

**Query:** I want to use @CurrentIteration('[Project]/Team') in TFS Query, **which I want to run from REST APIs**. 
e.g. @CurrentIteration(‘[MyProject]/MyTeam’) (I have always only one team associated with one project, not more than one)

**Issue:** In TFS query, I have defined @CurrentIteration to get iterations dynamically but, as per their protocols, this variable will only work from their Web Portal and not from REST APIs.

**Resolution:** If we add team name as a parameter in braces with @CurrentIteration then, that will work for REST APIs and Web Portal both. But now when I add team as parameter I am getting below error in TFS.

**Error:** The ability of the @CurrentIteration macro to accept a team is disabled. 
(I did research on it and it looks like, this ability might be available only in Azure DevOps Server 2019 and later version. I am not sure about this. Need help here.)

[Reference link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=vsts#client-restrictions-on-the-use-of-the-currentiteration-macros)
[Reference link2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/03/01/currentiteration-team-parameter-offset/)
[Reference link3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/mar-05-vsts#clarify-query-iteration-schedules-with-the-currentiteration-team-parameter)

Can anyone have any idea why i am getting this error? 
Where can i have option to enable this ability in my on premise TFS web portal?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, this feature will be avaiable only on TFS 2019.

See the official featuers timeline [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/):

> Clarify query iteration schedules with the @CurrentIteration Team parameter: 2019

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am bit confused about when these both, Azure DevOps 2019 and TFS (on premise) 2019, will release and how i will test?. I hear the news that TFS 2019 RC1 should release in December.

Comment: Azure DevOps it's in the cloud and updated frequently, the feature is available there now. TFS 2019 available from 11/19 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/release-notes/azuredevops2019#rc1-release-date-november-19-2018 (the feature exist in this version) BTW - TFS is not called Azure DevOps Server.